# Page is scrolling itself after refreshing html page even without adding js

Tags: html, css

> ```
> HTML
> ```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" >
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div div__site">
  <div class="div div__videoWrap">
    <video id="bgVideo" autoplay muted loop  controls class="video-block__video">
      <source type='video/mp4'  src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>

    <section style="background-color: aqua;"  class="sec sec__two"><p>Sec2</p></section>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> my css

```
.div.div__videoWrap{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.div.div__videoWrap #bgVideo{
 object-fit: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.sec.sec__two{
  height:1000px;
}
```

Without a video tag, everything works fine. But with the video tag, if I refresh the page (within 2-3 refresh clicks), the page scrolls down itself, and I have not written JavaScript.I searched in google but found no helpful code. I also don't want to use `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` to scroll to top after refreshing page.Please help... Thanks with advance

Comment: i didn't find any issue with these codes, please your all css codes to get the exact issue

Comment: my css code is simple as above,i have already provided my full css code

Comment: and it only appears me after 2-3 refresh clicks

Comment: everything is working fine. no issue found I've checked with IE and Crome. I refreshed page more than 10 times , No issue.

Comment: i didnt find any issue, I am using firefox browser

Comment: i am using chrome

Comment: i cant understand..

Comment: I even restarted my pc still same problem

Comment: I have added an answer please check it. its working in chrome

Comment: IE and firefox works fine,but in chrome it is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your question is a bit misdirectional. On checking your code it seems that you want to make your page stay on the top where you have embedded your video.

You can achieve this by adding overflow property. In your css just add this **overflow-anchor: none;**

Here's your changes:

```
.div.div__videoWrap{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.div.div__videoWrap #bgVideo{
overflow-anchor: none;
object-fit: cover;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.sec.sec__two{
height:1000px;
}
```

if you want to read more about this overflow property you can read it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor

Comment: Thanks for your help you were right now problem solved thanks,but why did't it happened on ie,firefox and only on chrome

Comment: i learnt a new browser behaviour because of you thanks

Comment: Different browsers work differently. Some browsers follow full guidelines of W3C while some don't follow it fully and hence the browser works differently.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.div.div__videoWrap{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }
    .div.div__videoWrap #bgVideo{
     object-fit: cover;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }
    .sec.sec__two{
      height:1000px;
    }
    .div__site{
      overflow-anchor: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div div__site">
  <div class="div div__videoWrap">
    <video id="bgVideo" autoplay muted loop  controls class="video-block__video">
      <source type='video/mp4'  src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>

    <section style="background-color: aqua;"  class="sec sec__two"><p>Sec2</p></section>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added one css effect in your codes, try this